# How to convert TSV/CSV to PDF table

Tags: bash, pdf, command-line, converters, csv

Is there a straightforward way to convert a tab-separated file (or CSV) to a PDF document using command line tools? As far as I can tell, enscript will do the raw text to pdf, but I need the columns to line up in the PDF. Any idease?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Another option might be to make two passes over your file and determine the maximum width of all fields on the first pass, then output into a format just wider than that on the second - all using `awk`. So, if your `input.csv` looks like this:

```
r1c1,r1c2longpuppy,r1c3
r2c1dddf,r2c2,r2c3
r3c1,r3c2,r3c3iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

You could do this:

```
awk -F, '
   FNR==NR { # first pass, determine max length of each field
      for(f=1;f<=NF;f++){if(length($f)>widest[f])widest[f]=length($f)}
      next;
   }
   { # second pass, print each field just wider than widest
      for(f=1;f<=NF;f++){
         printf "%-" widest[f] "s ",$f
      }
      printf "\n"
   }' file.csv file.csv
```

which gives you this:

```
r1c1     r1c2longpuppy r1c3
r2c1dddf r2c2          r2c3
r3c1     r3c2          r3c3iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

which you can, presumably, pass to `enscript`.

**Original Answer**

If your CSV file can be massaged to look like this

**file.csv**

```
col1,col2,col3
----,----,----
r1c1,r1c2,r1c3
r2c1,r2c2,r2c3
r3c1,r3c2,r3c3
```

You can convert it to a `PDF` by translating the commas into pipe symbols (`|`) and running it through `pandoc` to convert a *"pipe table"* into a stand-alone `PDF` like this:

```
tr ',' '|' < file | pandoc -s -o result.pdf
```

Documentation [here](http://pandoc.org/README.html).

Comment: using Libre Office: `soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export input.csv`